# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have a laptop with a 500 GB HDD and windows 7.I wanted to install Ubuntu on it.it normally has a "c" partition as ntfs that is labelled in Ubuntu as sda3 and is 50 gb (this is where I have windows installed) another partition D with remaining space that I use to store data and Ubuntu sees as sda4 and sda1 and sda2 are both 100mbish of stuff with no recovery on one and some system reserved thing on the other(when I installed Windows it made me do it).

I wanted to install Ubuntu on a completely different partition because I want for them not to mix so I resized my d partition with some program and made another partition that was 50gb and is recognised as g by windows and as sda5 by Ubuntu(didn't format it because I wanted it as ext4 and I couldn't do that in Windows.
After I booted with my DVD(both options UEFI and normal it does not recognise that I have windows installed and prompted me to erase all data or chose something else so I did that.

And now I am at the screen with all the partitions and I am not sure what to do because I don't want to accidentally wipe my c(sda3) or d(sda4) drives but want to install Ubuntu solely on sda5
(It is labelled as unknown but I clicked on it and chose ext4 and clicked format but left mount point blank because I am not sure what to choose.and have device boot loader selected on /dev/sda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mount point to / and install boot loader to /dev/sda. It will work, carry on.